# Error A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly repspond after a period of time

Tags: c#, tcp, console

I am trying to establish a TCP connection using the console application, but the code that I am using produces an error.

I am able to ping the other device successfully from the PC.

Windows Firewall is off and there is no other active firewall on the computer.

The error I am getting is.

**Error:**

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly repspond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host had failed to respond

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    TcpClient tcpclnt1 = new TcpClient();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

                    tcpclnt1.Connect("10.112.90.246", 13002);
                    // use the ipaddress as in the server program

                    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                    Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");

                    String str = Console.ReadLine();
                    Stream stm = tcpclnt1.GetStream();

                    ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);
                    Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

                    stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

                    byte[] bb = new byte[100];
                    int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);

                    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                        Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

                    tcpclnt1.Close();
                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error "+ e.Message + e.StackTrace);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what is wrong here.

Comment: A tcpdump captured b/w client and server would help.Are you seeing 'Connected' message that you have as a log in code?

Comment: Nop... after the connecting message i am simply getting the mentioned error.

Comment: Likely there isn't proper route. Please share the tcpdump. You are likely to see `SYN` packet going out from client but not `SYN-ACK`from server.